# How to make a correct select query on google endpoint?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I created an Android project using Google Cloud Endpoints, I created a model class Poll.java and now I want to make a query in the PollEndpoint.java class, to retrieve a poll with a specific author.

This is the query code in PollEndpoint.java

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getSpecificPoll", path="lastpoll")
public Poll getSpecificPoll(@Named("creator") String creator) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Poll specificPoll = null;

    try {

        Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Poll where creator 
                                        ='"+creator+"'");
        specificPoll = (Poll) query.getSingleResult();
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return specificPoll;
    }
```

The code in the client part is:

```
 private class PollQuery extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Poll> {
        @Override
        protected Poll doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Poll pollQuery = new Poll();

            Pollendpoint.Builder builderQuery = new Pollendpoint.Builder(
                      AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new
                      JacksonFactory(),null);

            builderQuery = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builderQuery);

            Pollendpoint endpointQuery = builderQuery.build();



                  try {
                    pollQuery =
                                        endpointQuery.getSpecificPoll("Bill").execute();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                  if (pollQuery != null){
                  System.out.println(pollQuery.getKeyPoll().getId());
                  } else System.out.println("Null query");

                  return null;
            }
```

The problem is that the server throw an exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: FROM clause of query has class com.development.pollmeproject.Poll but no alias
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:302)
```

I think that the query statement is not correct, how can I write a correct one?

Comment: This is a JPA/SQL query question. It is not about Android or cloud endpoints, so I'm going to change your tags.  Are you new to JPA/SQL? If so, and you are using the datastore, then you might consider using Objectify instead of JPA - I think it is a much easier and more effective way to use the datastore.

Comment: Yes the question is about JPQL, not about Objectify or what alternative solution to use. Let's focus on his actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided is NOT valid JPQL. JPQL is more of the form

```
SELECT p FROM Poll p WHERE p.creator = :creatorParam
```

The error message does tell you that though, so I'm not sure why you're not sure of it